# Single Page Site and Back Button Confusion

Tags: javascript, css, single-page-application

I have been searching for hours about how to do this, trying different things and not succeeding.

All I want to do is make a one-page site that shows/hides divs and does one simple animation.  I have already made it do everything I want and look the way I want it to look:  When you click a link in my navbar, there is a script that runs that hides one div, shows another, and also changes the size of the header image. This is all done with simple JS and CSS, but the back button doesn't work and the URL does not change even when I make the link a hash anchor.  Maybe having all the divs on the index and showing/hiding them isn't even the best way to do this.

The implementation of the HTML5 History API (If I should even be using that) has got me stumpped, and I can't seem to find a simple straightforward working example of this.

Can anyone point me to a fiddle or codepen of something like this working properly?

This is the basics of what I'm doing:

Link:

```
<a href="#work" onclick="work()">Work</a>
```

Function:

```
    function work() {
        document.getElementById("work").style.cssText = 'display: block; opacity: 1;'
        document.getElementById("about").style.cssText = 'display: none; opacity: 0;'
        document.getElementById("hero").style.cssText = 'height: 85px; transition: 200ms ease-in-out;'
        document.getElementById("introcontainer").style.cssText = 'visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;  transition: visibility 200ms, opacity 200ms linear;';
    }
```

When my "Work" link is clicked, "about" is hidden, "introcontainer" is hidden, height of "hero" is changed, and "work" is displayed.  I have two other "pages" and they function the same way.

Answer (score 0):

History API is made just for such scenarios , instead of scanning url hashes and running complex `if else` you can use pushState to keep track of application state and decide what happens at each state.

The gist of this API is when you push something using pushState it gets returned to you on popState (on hitting back button).

```
history.pushState(objState,title,Url);
```

The first argument is where we pass stuff that will help identify application state you can put anything but it has to be enclosed in an object

I will ignore the 2nd one(pass any string). 3rd one is what URL bar would show relative to current path on executing `PushState()`

Assuming you have nav something like this

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="about" title="About us">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact" title="Contact Us">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="team" title="Team">Team</a></li>
</ul>
```

assign click handlers for pushing state

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    history.pushState({url:targetUrl}, targetUrl, targetUrl);
    applyState(targetUrl); //will show div associated with this anchor 
});
```

Now when user clicks a link you need to push something related to this say its href or title to  identify it later (I've used its href but you are free to use anything) after it gets pushed  you may animate and show div associated with this link eg. If I click `<a href="work">` then push “work” and show the div that holds your work details(while minimizing/hiding other divs) .Your url reads *xyz/work* atm

Next if I click `<a href="contact">` state for contact  gets pushed and same way  it's associated div  gets highlighted.Your url reads *xyz/contact* atm

Now when I hit back history will pop and url will change from *xyz/contact* to *xyz/work* popping the latest inactive state (wiz. work and not contact!)

If you have assigned handler for onpopstate you can catch the popped content

```
window.onpopstate = function(e) {
    var popie = e.state ? e.state.url : null;
    applyState(popie);
}
```

so  popie would be “work” , applyState will do its fancy animation and show work div

applyState might look like

```
function  applyState(url) {
    $('#status').text('Current active page ' + url);
    switch(url){
     case "work": //show work details div hide others
    break;

     case "about": //show aboutdetails div hide others
    break;

 }
```

Comment: Hey there, I have been using your fix, but one thing that was an issue was refreshing the page and direct links.  When the page is refreshed, it goes back to the initial state, and the direct link does not work. I know that I could make the page exist at url/work, but then I would have to pull content from those divs because manually keeping the pages updated is not smart.